# How to integrate a custom Project Template and Wizard into Visual Studio package?

Tags: visual-studio-addins, envdte, vsx, vspackage, vs-extensibility

**Current Situation**

I have created a Custom Project template with an attached wizard which will ask the user for some options and it will generate some code (for instance: INIT method, some objects initialization). I have deployed this via the VSIX Project and everything is fine.

**The Goal**

I have also an empty VS package. So My question is: How to import the template and the wizard into the package? Because I want to be able to update the package later on with menu items etc.

**Problems**

There is little info on the net about how to create and extend VS Package. I followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc512961%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). But there I have created a Project template which is basic and since I don't know how to extended it, I think it will be a lot easier to import an already created Project template with a wizard.

**In Other Words**

I want my final product to be just the same as C++ win32 console application (which appears in the c++ section. When clicked - wizard supports the user for generating a new project with his preferences) but for C# as well.

**Extra Info**

I read that Add ins are deprecated in the newer versions of VS as well as Macros. Therefore I chose VS Package Project System (more extensible than custom templates). I saw some explanation about A Project SubType (a.k.a ProjectFlavor - lets you customize or flavor the behavior of the project systems of Visual Studio) but I did not found any tutorials or samples except Managed Package Framework for Projects (it's too complex for me).

Comment: Fix your link please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Assumptions

For simplicity, I'm going to assume the following.

1. You are creating a **Project Template** which creates a new project for a project system that is **already supported** by Visual Studio. For example, you might be creating a template which creates a new C# project.
2. You are using Visual Studio 2012 or newer to **create** your extension.
3. You want this extension to be **usable in Visual Studio 2012 and newer**.
4. Your wizard customizations to the project are more complicated than can be performed by creating a "simple" project followed by automatically installing one or more NuGet packages (installation of NuGet packages as part of creating a new project does not require a custom wizard).

### Design Strategy

The general design of your final extension will be the following.

- Your extension will comprise of both the project template and an assembly containing your `IWizard` implementation.
- The extension will be bundled into a single **.vsix** file for distribution.

This design allows you to update your template, wizard, or both at any point in the future by simply creating a new version of your **.vsix**.

### Implementation

Since there are many steps, I created a repository on GitHub to show the complete process.

https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/VsixWizardSample

Comment: Thank you very much, for your time and effort. No body replied me so far except you. The example is straight forward and to the point. Furthermore it does not deal with any GAC signing as I can see in .vstemplate file . But I already have exaclty the same solution. I was asking about how to add them into a basic Project System VS Package. I will explain you why and maybe you can give me your advice.

Comment: I need to have templates not only for a particular project type but aslo for others.(class library, console application, form application both in c++ and c#). Moreover I want one to be able to develop this extension later on by adding some menus toolbox es and code highlighter etc. But I don’t know it now so I prefer to make it more generic instead of just creating a normal template.

Comment: One Remark: I want this extension to be usable not only for VS 12 but for VS 2005 VS 2008 and VS 2010. My company own licence for 2005 and 2010

Comment: @Vla (Re: the 2nd comment) VSIX extensions can be updated by simply distributing a new version of the VSIX. You could update any part of it that needed changing. Also, you can include multiple templates targeting multiple project systems all in the same extension.

Comment: @Vla (Re: the 1st comment) A project system VS Package is not relevant to this question at all (I believe you have misinterpreted their use cases).

Comment: @Vla (Re: the 3rd comment) Visual Studio extensions changed significantly for VS 2010 (they are much easier now). If you want help for extending an earlier version, you should make a new question with that as the first line.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I can Create a multi project templates with the wizard wrapped up with VSIX project and then at a later time I can extend that and include VS Package to this VSIX Project

Comment: But where is the point if VSIX is not working for previous version of VS. I need to develop another extension. So my work will be double